# onClick Button Crash

Tags: java, android

I've just started using Android Studio, and I've followed a tutorial on linking my button to a webpage, however, following it exact my app crashed and I get a bunch of errors, I've tried looking online but I can seem to find what i've done wrong. Am I missing something?

These are the errors:

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.josh.test2, PID: 2264
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method browser1(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

And this is my code what I followed:

Frag1.java

```
package com.example.josh.test2;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;



public class Frag1 extends Fragment {

View myView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, container, false);
    return myView;


    public View onCreateView(Bundle savedInstance){

        View rootView = Inflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragmet_view);

        Button browse = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.co.uk"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

layout.xml

```
<Button
    android:text="Test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="18sp"
    android:id="@+id/button"/>
```

Comment: I know this is probably the worst issue, but **android:onClick=browser1** event gets fired when public void browser1(View) gets defined in an Activity, but if you are expecting this to be called inside a Fragment, you are going to cry. If still you want to persist this behavior then you might have to define **public void browser1(View) inside the Activity that is hosting the fragment**

Comment: Your code lacks a method called `browser1 (View)`

Comment: Use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment` for `Fragment` class.

Comment: @SatanPandeya thanks! that got rid of the underline on getContext!

Comment: Use: `LayoutInflator.from(this)` instead of `Inflater.from(getContext())`

Comment: Is the code formatting correct? because I see a method inside another method.

Comment: @SatanPandeya .from and fragment_view are still red on the same line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove `android:onClick="browser1"` from any layout XML.

Then, you can add your button logic from the Java code

```
public class YourFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    // TODO: Implement onCreateView

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Handle click
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not make the method in the fragment, system will search in the activity NOT in the fragment, so you have to define the method in the activity not in the fragment.

the better solution is to make the `onClick` method dynamically:

```
 public View onCreateView(Bundle savedInstance){

 View rootView = Inflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragmet_view);

 Button browse = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
 browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v){
           Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.co.uk"));
           startActivity(browserIntent);
      }
 });

 return rootView;
 }
```

Comment: So do the same except in MainActivity,java?

Comment: @ODoe No, you need to remove `android:onClick` from the XML and define using Java as shown. (In the Fragment)

Comment: you don't have to define the onClick in the mainActivity, just remove the `android:onClick` from the xml and define it in the fragment, note that the rootView is the main view of the fragment

Comment: @cricket_007 The bits you suggested have gone red? I removed the onClick and then added what you said to the fragment. https://gyazo.com/ec8488c9d7184fe31bc6474d7db36236

Comment: this should be in the onCreateView method of the fragment, rootView is the inflated view for the fragment, and make sure you import the OnClickListener

Comment: @KhalidTaha I've done all that, but one thing I don't understand is what you been by rootView is the inflated view, I only started having a go at Android yesterday so I'm still pretty basic. That's still underlined red.

Comment: @ODoe `rootView` is the variable that you would be returning from `onCreateView`. It is the View variable that is being inflated.

Comment: see the updated answer, the rootView is the view that handles the xml file that you created which contains the button browse.

Comment: @KhalidTaha https://gyazo.com/64f943ee2666fa2751687a4312c668c6 this is what I have

Comment: can you post all your fragment code by updating the question ?

Comment: @Khalid `onCreateView` has more parameters than that. One of which is an `inflater`